# Debezium Configs Topic Prefix Exception

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium

i use debezium/connect:2.1.4.Final image and try to create a postgresql connector.
Here is my config

```
{
    "name": "debezium-connector",
    "config": {
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
        "database.hostname": "hostname",
        "database.port": "port",
        "database.user": "user",
        "database.dbname": "dbname",
        "database.password": "password",
        "slot.name": "slotname",
        "publication.name": "publicationname",

"database.server.name": "debezium.collector.dbname.events",
"heartbeat.interval.ms": "5000",

"plugin.name": "pgoutput",
"tombstones.on.delete": "false",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"database.whitelist": "public",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"snapshot.mode": "never",
"table.include.list": "public.table_1,public.table_2"
    }
}
```

When i try to Post /connectors with this body, i get an error:
Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nThe 'topic.prefix' value is invalid:

but when i read debezium documentation, i see that database.server.name is used for topic prefix. what should i do?

Comment: Maybe it wants you to provide a value, even if it's an empty string?